# PhpStorm can not push to git repository

Tags: git, push, phpstorm

I am using Windows 8, PhpStorm 8.0.2, git

I am trying to push my projects to the remove git repository (they are hosted on the github and bitbucket).

Last message that I see in the Version Control Console of the php storm is:

`git -c core.quotepath=false push --progress --porcelain origin refs/heads/master:master`

And it waits on it forever, it does not show any error or output from this command

If I'm pushing project manualy (from command line, or from console tab in PhpStorm with command `git push origin`) it works well. Also I can commit changes into my local repository.

I've tried to disable windows firewall and added both git and phpstorm into the firewall rules - it does not help.

When I'm using command
`ssh -T git@github.com` it also works well and gives me message about successfully access to the github.

So, the only thing that does not working is pushing to remove git repository via PhpStorm menu.

What can I do to fix this problem?

Thanks

Comment: If nothing helps, using the command from the console tab is just three keystrokes away: Ctrl-Shift-X, Up, Enter ;-)

Comment: What happens when you run that exact command from a Command Prompt? Maybe it expects some input and PhpStorm is not aware of that and waits forever for it to complete.

Comment: When I run command from Command Prompt it doesn't ask any questions, but simply pushes commit to the server.

Comment: Do other `git` operations with the remote repository (`fetch`, `pull`) work from PhpStorm?

Comment: Just checked: no, it does not work either. Same problem: it's simply freezes on the `git -c core.quotepath=false pull --progress --no-stat -v --progress origin master` command with no output or errors

Comment: Have the same issue. Still not solved?

Comment: No, I did not solved this problem, even after update to the phpstorm 9. But I had created some command line tools, that run git push/pull for current project and now I'm using them for this task

Answer (score 4, accepted):

go to phpstorm -> settings -> version control -> git and choose "built in" on the "ssh executable" section's dropdown.

Answer (score 0):

For me choosing "native" instead of default "built in" worked fine.
OSX ElCapitan - PhpStorm 10